# vc6 ado execute buffer overflow

Tags: visual-c++, ado, buffer-overflow, visual-c++-6

So I've been having a problem in production that was seemingly exposed by a service pack upgrade.  It appears to be some kind of buffer overflow in the Execute method of an ado _ConnectionPtr object.  The following code is what produces the buffer overflow:

```
char szStatement[600];
sprintf(szStatement, "UPDATE ROUTING_MASTER SET CNTNR_WGT_EST = %g WHERE CNTNR_ID = '%s'", 
                         spLineItem->CntnrItemsWeight, (LPCTSTR) spLineItem->ContainerID);

m_spCN->Execute(szStatement,&var,adCmdText);
```

After the execute method it tramples one of my member variables (_bstr_t) and the next time the application tries to access the trampled member variable it throws an exception.  I can tell it's being trampled because I have my member variable in the watch window and immediatly after the Execute method completes I see that member variable has changed (m_bstrDate):

[image]

var is declared in the header file as:

```
variant_t var;
BOOL m_bUseStorePutCntnr;
_bstr_t m_bstrDate, m_bstrTime;
```

It would appear that the assignment to &var is what is doing it because if I change it to the following it doesn't trample my member variable:

```
m_spCN->Execute(szStatement, NULL, adCmdText);
```

I'm not sure that this is related to the service pack as I see this in my development environment as well and visual studio somehow just keeps going next time it has to access that member variable.

Any idea as to why this would cause a buffer overflow?

Comment: Hm, you're using `sprintf`, which doesn't check buffer size, could the buffer overflow be caused by that?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be as when I debug it the size of szStatement looks fine.  Looks to be properly null terminated and less than 600 bytes (size of szStatement). I've also added the declaration for szStatement above.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Visual C/C++ v6.0 with ADO environment setup and therefore I could not verify anything wrote below.

But it is obvious that the address of the reserved memory block passed with second parameter of `Execute` method is not large enough.

I could not find in MSDN the class `_ConnectionPtr` and also nothing about method `Execute` of this class. But I have found the page [ADO interface _ConnectionPtr](http://www.databaseskill.com/2539530/). According to this page the prototype for method `Execute` is:

```
_RecordsetPtr Connection :: Execute (_bstr_t CommandText, VARIANT * RecordsAffected, long Options)
```

So the second parameter is a pointer to structure [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627.aspx).

But you have defined member variable `var` as being an object of class [variant_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx) which encapsulates **VARIANT** structure.

I'm 100% that the size of structure **VARIANT** is different to size of class **variant_t**.

You should be able to verify that by inserting into your code:

```
TRACE("Size of VARIANT is %u and size of variant_t is %u\n",sizeof(VARIANT),sizeof(variant_t));
```

My conclusion:

**You pass the wrong object to method `Execute`!**

Your application should work with replacing in your header file **variant_t** by **VARIANT** and perhaps clear all bytes of the structure with

```
memset(&var,0,sizeof(var));
```

before calling method `Execute` although I'm quite sure this is not really needed.

If you want to additionally use class **variant_t**, you have to define nevertheless also a **VARIANT** structure and attach it to **variant_t**  object.

That would mean you need in header file:

```
VARIANT var;
variant_t RecordsAffected;
```

And in the source file:

```
memset(&var,0,sizeof(var));   // Most likely not really needed.
m_spCN->Execute(szStatement,&var,adCmdText);
RecordsAffected.Attach(&var);
```

Please let me know if I made mistakes on the code snippets which I could not test at all as well as any other wrong information in my answer.